# ‘meteor mongo’ command not working in meteor-1.4.1.1 (windows 10)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using **windows 10**. MongoDB version 3.2.6, node version 4.4.7, Meteor version 1.4.1.1. I am in correct directory. But I get that error after running '*meteor mongo*' (**Click Screenshot**). Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFi02.png)

Comment: Which mongodb version do you run? You can use `mongod --version` to find out.

Comment: db version v3.2.6-rc0

Comment: @RaqibAbdullah Did you manage to resolve this - I have the same issue.

Comment: @Kildareflare No bro.